# Store result in Execute Sql task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, execute-sql-task

I have written a stored procedure which will return the columns BEID, Date_of_txn, Txn_Amount as a result after the execution. I am getting the result manually when I run the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio. But I want to execute this stored procedure with "Execute SQL" task in SSIS and want to store the result in a variable. How can I do that?

I am not aware of how to store the result in result set as when I run the package, the package got failed every time.

- Result set: `Single Row`
- Connection Type: `OLE DB`
- Connection: `LocalHost.Fino_Detail`
- SQLStatement: `Exec sp_HighAmount 02, 2019`

Stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_HighAmount]
    (@Month INT,
     @Year INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        BEID, DATE_OF_TXN, SUM(Txn_amount) AS Txn_Amount 
    FROM 
        Fino_Sales
    WHERE
        SUBSTRING(Date_of_txn, 6, 2) = @Month
        AND SUBSTRING(Date_of_txn, 1, 4) = @Year
    GROUP BY
        BEID, Date_of_txn
    HAVING 
        SUM(Txn_Amount) BETWEEN 35001 AND 50000
        AND SUM(commission_paid) > 350
END
```

Comment: Use a variable of type `object` https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/05/28/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-result-set-enumerator/

Comment: First explain what you want to do with results, execute Sql Task may not be the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... 
group by BEID, Date_of_txn
...
```

There is a high probability that such query returns multiple rows, therefore a resul set should be switched to: "**Full result set**" and the output to be mapped to a variable with a type: **Object**, with a further `foreach` task to traverse of each row.

A good step-by-step walkthrough can read: [Execute SQL Task in SSIS Full Row Set](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/execute-sql-task-in-ssis-full-row-set/)